# Where to put try and except statement to prevent user entering: a letter and above given amount?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a trivia game; I am still new to python. Where should I place my try and except statements to prevent the user entering a letter and an amount higher than xScore(a or b)?

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, answera, answerb, answerc, answerd, correct):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = [answera, answerb, answerc, answerd]
        self.correct = correct
    def ask(self):
        print(self.question)
        for n in range(0, 4):
            print("   ", n + 1, ")", self.answers[n])
        answer = int(input("enter your answer >"))
        return answer == self.correct

def right(x):
    x * 2
    return int(x)



def questions1():
    aScore = 10
    print('you are able to wager up to', aScore)
    bet = int(input('Enter points to wager:'))
    question1 = Question("What does the NFL stand for?", "National Football League", "National Fun Live", "No Fun League",
                         "Narcs Fuzz and Larp", 1)
    if question1.ask() == True:
        print("You are correct")
        aScore += right(bet)
    else:
        print("incorrect")
        aScore -= bet

    print('you are able to wager up to', aScore)
    bet = int(input('Enter points to wager:'))
    question2 = Question("Who won the superbowl last year (2016)", "Atlanta Falcons", "New England Patriots", "Carolina Panthers",
                         "Toronto Maple Leafs", 2)
    if question2.ask() == True:
        print("You are correct")
        aScore += right(bet)
    else:
        print("incorrect")
        aScore -= bet
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent user entering a letter (or any non-integer) using a `try... except`, you can put the `try...except` around the `input`:

```
while True:
    try:
        answer = int(input("enter your answer >"))
    except ValueError:
        print('Answer must be an integer.')
    else:
        break
```

This will keep prompting until the user enters an integer. The `else` statement runs if the `except` is not hit, so the flow `break`s out of the loop.

To prevent the user entering an amount higher than their score, you can test their input after the `try...except`

```
while True:
    try:
        answer = int(input('Enter points to wager:'))
    except ValueError:
        print('Answer must be an integer.')
    else:
        if answer < aScore:
            break
        else:
            print("You don't have enough points for that wager!")
```